# The performance in relation to the interval

Tags: javascript, performance

I have made an intermittent bar, the problem is that I am afraid, that something so insignificant requires so much, with this I mean that in 1 minute more than **120** `intervals` were made, is there a **more efficient way to do this**?

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
var e = document.getElementById("bar"), flag = true;
setInterval(()=>{
if(flag) {
e.style.display = "none";
flag = !flag;
}
else {
e.style.display = "block";
flag = !flag;
}
},400);
});
```

```css
#barText {
font-family: monospace; color: purple; font-size: 25px;
font-weight: 600;
position: absolute;
}
#bar {
width: 2.2px;
height: 29px;
background-color: purple;
margin: 0 0 0 22%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<i id="barText">Overflow</i><div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The CPU requirement of executing code at 2 frames per second is so insignificant as to not be worth thinking about. Games commonly execute at `setInterval(x,50)`. In fact, `requestAnimationFrame()` is equivalent to `setInterval(x,16.7)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use a CSS animation and not use JS at all.

```css
#barText {
    font-family: monospace; color: purple; font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: 600;
    position: absolute;
}
#bar {
    width: 2.2px;
    height: 29px;
    background-color: purple;
    margin: 0 0 0 22%;
    animation: blink-animation .6s steps(2, start) infinite;
    -webkit-animation: blink-animation .6s steps(2, start) infinite;
}
@keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes blink-animation {
  to {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
<i id="barText">Overflow</i><div id="bar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Which browser is `@-webkit-keyframes` and `-webkit-animation` required for? (It isn't necessary for _Chrome_)